# Scala Spec2 Mockito: matchers for non-primitive arguments: any, isA

Tags: scala, arguments, mockito, matcher, specs2

I am writing a mock object like below:

```
import org.specs2.mock._
import com...MonetaryValue
import com...Voucher
import org.mockito.internal.matchers._

/**
 * The fake voucher used as a mock object to test other components
 */
case class VoucherMock() extends Mockito {
  val voucher: Voucher = mock[Voucher]

  //stubbing
  voucher.aMethod(any(classOf[MonetaryValue])) answers {arg => //some value to be return based on arg} 

  def verify() = {
    //verify something here
  }
}
```

The stubbing step throws an exception:

```
 ...type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Class[com...MonetaryValue](classOf[com...MonetaryValue])
[error]  required: scala.reflect.ClassTag[?]
[error]   voucher.aMethod(any(classOf[MonetaryValue])) answers {arg => //some value to be return based on arg}
```

I want to get the value from the argument and return a value based on this argument, like this: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#11

I have tried with `isA, anyObject...`

What is the correct argument matcher for this case? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `any[MonetaryValue]`. Here is a fully working example:

```
class TestSpec extends Specification with Mockito { def is = s2"""
  test ${
    val voucher: Voucher = mock[Voucher]

    // the asInstanceOf cast is ugly and 
    // I need to find ways to remove that
    voucher.aMethod(any[MonetaryValue]) answers { m => m.asInstanceOf[MonetaryValue].value + 1}
    voucher.aMethod(MonetaryValue(2)) === 3
  }
  """
}

trait Voucher {
  def aMethod(m: MonetaryValue) = m.value
}
case class MonetaryValue(value: Int = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the exhaustive answer above.
Now instead of MonetaryValue type, I need to pass a complex parameter Map[String,Seq[String]]. How can I define the matcher? Thank you very much, Eric.

Comment: any[Map[String,Seq[String]]] doesn't work.
I tried to define a new matcher via ArgumentMatcher (and used argThat) but I got another error.

Comment: Everything works fine for me. Can you open another question showing your exact attempts and corresponding error messages?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157783/scala-spec2-mockito-argument-matchers-with-complex-types

Comment: I've been struggling with this thing for like 30 minutes (which is longer than it sounds). Thanks.