# Scala Spec2 Mockito: Argument matchers with complex types

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, mockito, matcher, specifications

I'm trying to write a mock for a web service with Mockito. The mock should simulate a POST request using the play WS library.

```
/**
 * Mock for the  Web Service
 */
case class WSMock() extends Mockito {
  val wsRequestHolder: play.api.libs.ws.WS.WSRequestHolder = mock[play.api.libs.ws.WS.WSRequestHolder]

  val wsResponse: play.api.libs.ws.Response = mock[play.api.libs.ws.Response]
  wsResponse.status returns 200
  wsResponse.body returns "BODY RESP FROM WS"

  val futureResponse = scala.concurrent.Future { wsResponse }

  wsRequestHolder.post(any[Map[String,Seq[String]]]) returns futureResponse
}
```

When running the test I get the following error:

```
[error]     InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
[error] Invalid use of argument matchers!
[error] 3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
[error] -> at org.specs2.mock.mockito.MockitoMatchers$class.any(MockitoMatchers.scala:24)
[error] 
[error] This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
[error]     //incorrect:
[error]     someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
[error] When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
[error] For example:
[error]     //correct:
[error]     someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
[error] 
[error] For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

It looks to me as the any[...] expression using a complex type (with nested type parameters) does not correctly get resolved into a matcher. However, I don't see where the raw type comes into play.
What is the proper way to specify such a matcher for a parameter `Map[String,Seq[String]]`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
wsRequestHolder.post(any[Map[String,Seq[String]]]) returns futureResponse
```

Note that `post` actually has a couple extra implicit parameters there:

```
def post [T] (body: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T]):
    Promise[Response]
```

...which probably need to be matched explicitly, as in [this spec2-users thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specs2-users/McqAuZbcAF8).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the wsRequestHolder.post method requires three parameters, so Mockito expects you to send three (e.g. any[]) matchers, but you provided matchers for only one of them.